# How to make a property set itself using {} instead of ;?

Tags: c#, .net, stack-overflow

Here is an interesting tidbit where I could not really find on the interwebs.  The idea is that if you have a property such as int a { get; set; } it could set itself.

How do you make the property set itself with int a { get { } set { } }?

What is happening inside of set;?

Here is what I tried to do:

```
public string Symbol { get { return Symbol; } set { Symbol = value; NotifyPropertyChangedEvent("Symbol");  } }
```

But it obviously creates a *Stack Overflow* because it is essentially calling itself over and over.

And I don't want to create 10-20 private variables to work along side of my properties, I want to know what is happening in set;.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know any way to avoid the verbosity, but a [code snippet can help](http://geekswithblogs.net/brians/archive/2010/07/27/inotifypropertychanged-with-less-typing-using-a-code-snippet.aspx)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`set;` just creates a private variable that you can't see. You'll need those 10-20 private variables, sorry.

Comment: Microsoft should then create a property specific keyword to access this "invisible variable", kind of like the value keyword.

Comment: @Rob You are free to go to Microsoft to suggest that.  SO however is not the place to go to suggest new C# features.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create private variables.

Unfortunately, that's the only way in the specific circumstance you have here.

Answer (score 1):

If you need custom logic, you'll need to provide the backing field yourself:

```
private string symbol;
public string Symbol 
{ 
    get { return symbol; } 
    set { symbol = value; NotifyPropertyChangedEvent("Symbol");  } 
}
```

---

> And I don't want to create 10-20 private variables to work along side of my properties, I want to know what is happening in set;.

With an automaticaly property (ie: `public string Symbol { get; set; }`), the compiler creates the backing field automatically.  However, there is no way to introduce logic (ie: raise your event) without managing the backing field(s) yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It generates a backing field for you when it gets compiled.  You cannot access it via intellisense because it has not been created yet.  It is equivalent to the following where '_a' has not been generated yet.

```
private int _a;
public int a
{
    get { return _a; }
    set { _a = value; }
}
```

You could, however, simply set the property itself from inside of your class.

```
public int a { get; set; }

a = ...;
```

Additionally, you can set modifiers on the get and set if you only want to be able to set it internally;

```
public int a { get; private set; }
```

Comment: Microsoft should then create a property specific keyword to access this "invisible variable", kind of like the value keyword.

Comment: @Rob If you want access to the backing field, I suggest using the 'propfull' snippet instead of the 'prop' snippet in the editor.  The primary benefit of the short hand '{ get; set; }' is so that you can easily come back later to add a backing field and full methods later on if required without having to recompile dependent code.